# Host File Won't Show Itself In Terminal

Tags: python, hosts

In trying to develop a website blocker program, I need to access the Hosts file.  I go into Terminal and type

> sudo python /private/ect/hosts>

And nothing shows up. The screen is blank. Any suggestions what may have gone wrong?[This photo is a shot of the terminal with no info on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGQ27.jpg)

Comment: Isn't there a typo? don't you mean `/private/etc/hosts`?

Comment: You want to execute the contents of `hosts` as a Python program…?!

Comment: Yep.....typo. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistyped the path, it is `/private/etc/hosts`. Also you have just created a new directory  and file with the mistyped name when using nano. And the /private/etc/hosts file is not python so doing `sudo python` won't do anything.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud...thanks.